# Clustering Identity Server 5.1.0 with SQL Server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am clustering Identity Server 5.1.0 referring to the following link

https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+Identity+Server+5.1.0#ClusteringIdentityServer5.1.0-ClusteringIS

The article mention that we need REGISTRY_LOCAL1 for each node which result in multiple database if I want to create multiple nodes.

Is it necessary to create REGISTRY_LOCAL1 database for each new node?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. REGISTRY_LOCAL db or by default WSO2CarbonDB is used to store the node specific config. That should not be shared among the nodes in the cluster.

Comment: Thanks 
i have one more query. Can i keep single database instead of having two DB, one for user-mgt and one for shared registry.